# Как должна выглядеть служба на смартфоне, чтобы принимать push уведомления с сервера без использования Firebase?

Tags: php, java, android, push

Надо создать приложение (под Android), которое бы принимало push уведомления с моего сервера (на php). Приложения на разных устройствах соответственно имеют свои идентификаторы устройств, по которым, собственно, и определяется, кто будет получателем уведомления.

Сторонние сервисы типа Firebase использовать не хочу.

Нужен конкретный пример или хотя бы принцип, как это делается.

Comment: Нужен бессмертный сервис, что довольно таки сложно и по сути нереально толком. Ну и соединение по сокету с сервером. Пытался я сделать это сам, без Firеbase и скажу, что оно того не стоит, для простого проекта так точно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без Firebase выбора то особого нет. По факту, всего 1 вариант - использовать [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) фоновый. А он периодически считывает инфу с сервера.

Т.е, у вас сервис в бекграунде либо:

1. Постоянно держит соединение с сервером, к примеру websocket соединение (но раз у вас там php, то не покатит), что жрёт батарею.
2. Либо периодически посылает запрос на сервер, чтоб проверить, есть ли новые пуши/сообщения. Следовательно пуши будут прилетать с задержкой, т.к. слишком часто посылать запросы плохо для батарии.

Но это не нативные **пуши**. Без Firebase/GCM нативные пуши не сделать.

Comment: А почему нельзя использовать тот принцип, который у Firebase/GCM ? Как он работает, что не садит батарею постоянными опросами сервера?

Comment: @kaaa под капотом там тоже websockets. А вот почему не садит - это интересный вопрос (:

Comment: с websockets можно разобраться и решить вопрос, но действительно ли идет постоянный опрос сервера или все таки сервер каким то образом сам находит устройство и отсылает ему уведомление?

Comment: @kaaa сервер чисто теоретически не может найти устройство, т.к. IP не статичный и за NAT'ом может быть. WebSockets в idle режиме почти ничего не едят. Тут всё зависит от частоты, с которой вы пингуете соединение и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте писать ваши уведомления в очередь а потом периодически считывать их из приложения;